# How can I show listings even when the class option 'draft' is set?

Tags: listings, draft, class-options

#### The question

Is it possible to configure the `listings` package to show the *content* in the `lstlisting` environment even if the global option `draft` is set?

#### Context

When working on a larger document, the `draft` option is useful to avoid compiling things like the table of contents, the glossary maybe even placeholder images for larger graphics every single time and hence allow for faster iteration on the document.

However, it seems that this option it also prompts the `listings` package to avoid showing the "content" of listings - while the captions are typeset correctly (try MWE with and without draft option further down, which includes all other packages my actual document uses).

I have checked the package documentation but it seems to me this is not a package-specific thing, but rather my ignorance of \LaTeX conventions getting in my way.

#### Minimal working example

```
%\documentclass[]{book}
\documentclass[draft]{book}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion,babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools} % This includes "amsmath" and the dcases environment among other things
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
%% ---------------- end of usepackages -------------
\begin{document}[caption=This will always be visible]
    \lstset{language=Java}
    // This is only visible when compiling without the draft option
    \begin{lstlisting}

        public class MyTest{
            int foo;
        }
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `listings` package provides an option called `final` that you can use for that. See section 2.2 of the `listings` doc:

> `final`
>
> Overwrites [sic] a global `draft` option.

Simply pass the `final` option to `listings` when you load the package:

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion,babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools} % This includes "amsmath" and the dcases environment among other things
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[final]{listings}% <=====
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
%% ---------------- end of usepackages -------------
\begin{document}[caption=This will always be visible]
    \lstset{language=Java}

    \begin{lstlisting}
        public class MyTest{
            int foo;
        }
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried [Arash's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246059/38377) but got a `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package listings` when I called `\lstdefinestyle`.  Instead, I added the `print` option to my style:

```
\lstdefinestyle{py}{
  language=Python,
  print   <============
}
```

That causes any listing with `style=py` to be included, even when `draft` is set.  The [docs](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), sec. 5.2, say that `print` "can be used to typeset particular listings despite using the draft option."