# tcolorbox/tcblisting: Draft mode erases boxes' content

Tags: tcolorbox, draft

Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{roughsketch}{listing only}

\begin{document}
\tcbinterruptdraftmode
\begin{roughsketch}
  Proof sketch.
\end{roughsketch}
\end{document}
```

This is what's rendered:
[image: Empty box]

**Question:**  In my attempt to "deactivate" draft mode, I used `\tcpinterruptdraftmode` above, but it had no impact, and so did `draftmode=false` on the box.  How can I keep using the class's draft mode but still have my boxes display their content?

Answer (score 4):

When you pass `draft` to the document class, it also forwards it to the `listings` package (loaded by the `most` option of tcolorbox) which suppresses the printing of all listings. You can get around this by passing `final` to the listings package.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{final}{listings} % test by commenting this out
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{roughsketch}{listing only}

\begin{document}

\begin{roughsketch}
  Proof sketch.
\end{roughsketch}

\begin{lstlisting}
  Proof sketch.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: listings]

Note this has nothing to do with `\tcbinterruptdraftmode`, which temporarily stops tcolorbox's "draft mode" that's started with `\tcbstartdraftmode`.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!  And this points to another possible solution: `\newtcblisting{roughsketch}{listing only,listing options=print}` which passes the `print` option to the listing, forcing it to appear (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246057/how-can-i-show-listings-even-when-the-class-option-draft-is-set).  Thanks!